# Need to convert date (m/d/yyyy) to custom quarterly format (yyyy/qq) in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dataset that just has the date represented by (m/d/yyyy) format. I would like to convert that into a new custom column to the custom format of (yyyy/qq) for example (2023/Q2) to match my other two datasets.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: what months are Q1 for your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making a new column with the following code:

```
Column = Table[DateColumn].[Year] & "/" & FORMAT(Table[DateColumn], "\Qq")
```

You should replace `Table` with your table name and `DateColumn` with the name of your date column.

EDIT:
In order to make the column, first in the data pop-out right-click on the table you want to add the column to and select "New column"

[image]

This will then give you a text editor at the top where you can enter the above code

[image]

If you'd prefer to make the column using M, you can use the following code, after select Custom Column under the Add Column tab:

```
Number.ToText(Date.Year([DateColumn])) & "/Q" & Number.ToText(Date.QuarterOfYear([DateColumn]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to follow your instructions but the table name doesnt appear nor does FORMAT when inputting the syntax when trying to create a new Custom Column. I added a picture circling the table and the column I am trying to use. I can write excel formulas all day but dont understand how PowerBI DAX formulas wrong.

Comment: @narsil Sorry, the code I gave was DAX code not M. M is the language used when creating power queries which is the language used in the editor you're showing in your screenshot. I'll update my answer to show you where you can add the column using DAX

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate you taking the time and your patience. Was able to get it that way I need it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/format-function-dax#custom-datetime-format-examples) to achieve this `yyyy/qq`:

```
=FORMAT(TableName[ColumnName],"YYYY") & "/Q" & FORMAT(TableName[ColumnName],"Q")
```

Comment: `FORMAT([Date], "yyyy/\Qq")`